# How to paginate Hibernate Many to Many relationship?

Tags: hibernate, pagination

```
public class Manager{

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@BatchSize(size = 10)
protected Collection<Employee> employees= new ArrayList<Employee>();
.
.
}
```

Suppose  Manager A has 30 Employee reporting to him. I want to see 10 at a time in my UI. I have used @BatchSize but it's not working. How do I use the same and provide any suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@BatchSize=10` tells Hibernate to load your collection by batch of 10 elements, but it will still load the complete collection.

You must implement a query and use `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResult` to control from which object you want to load and how many objects you want:

```
entityManager.createQuery("from Stuff").setFirstResult( 5 ).setMaxResults( 10 ).getResultList();
```

Comment: I have used Criteria/Query on Manager:

`Manager mgr= mgrCriteria.getManager(mngr.getName(),mngr.getEmailId());`

And doing something like:

`List<Employee> empList= new ArrayList<>(mgr.getEmployees()); to get list of employee.`

I am getting above empList using lazy loading. My intention was to get 10 records out of available say 100.That's why I have used BatchSize, which somehow not working. 
So, are there any way so that when I will be iterating through the list it should show me 10 records at a time and also any technique to mention which 10 out of 100 records.

Comment: This is what firstResult and maxResult are for (see my update with a code sample). You cannot load parts of a lazy collection, you must write a query to load a list of object Employee.